# Select table based on value from different table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are the tables:

```
info
+----------------------+
|userid|job_id|position|
+----------------------+
|1     |1     |2       |
|2     |2     |1       |
+----------------------+

job
+----------------+
|job_id|job_title|
+----------------+
|1     |army     |
|2     |grocer   |
+----------------+

army
+-----------------------+
|position|title   |income|
+------------------------+
|1       |private |$125  |
|2       |corporal|$175  |
+------------------------+

grocer
+-----------------------+
|position|title  |income|
+-----------------------+
|1       |bagger |$100  |
|2       |cashier|$120  |
+-----------------------+
```

I would like:

```
+----------------------------+
|id|job_title|position|income|
+----------------------------+
|1 |army     |corporal|$175  |
+----------------------------+
```

for whenever ***id 1*** is logged in and

```
+----------------------------+
|id|job_title|position|income|
+----------------------------+
|2 |grocer   |bagger  |$100  |
+----------------------------+
```

for whenever ***id 2*** is logged in

so,

```
if job_title=army

then select table army and info.position=army.position

if job_title=grocer

then select table grocer and  info.position=grocer.position
```

I cant quite figure this out. I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM info,job,army,grocer 
WHERE userid='$userid' and passid='$passid' and info.job_id=job.job_id;
```

which works for `job_title` but not `title` nor `income`. So I tried

```
SELECT * FROM info,job,army,grocer 
WHERE userid='$userid' and passid='$passid' and info.job_id=job.job_id and info.position=army.position;
```

which worked for **id 1** but not **id 2**. I need something like

```
SELECT * FROM info,job,army,grocer 
WHERE userid='$userid' and passid='$passid' and info.job_id=job.job_id and info.position=_.position;
```

where the _ is either army or grocer, based on **userid** and `position`

Comment: Normalize your data and all such problems would go away.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but the best way to do what you're asking is quite contrary to what you have set up. Ideally you would create a `positions` table that incorporates all positions and assigns a `foreign key` to the job each user is assigned to. Breaking up your tables that relate in some way only causes hassles like this, which in turn, can also cause very slow, high cost queries.

Look up *database normalization* for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
--drop table #info
SELECT  *
INTO #info
FROM    
(
    select 1 as userid , 1 as job_id, 2 as position
        UNION
    select 2 as userid , 2 as job_id, 1 as position
) a

--drop table #job
SELECT  *
into #job
FROM    
(
SELECT 1 as job_id , 'army' as job_title
    union
SELECT 2 as job_id , 'grocer' as grocer
) a

--drop table #army
SELECT  *
into #army
FROM    
(
select 1 as position , 'private' as title, 125 as income
    union
select 2 as position , 'corporal' as title, 175 as income
) a

--drop table #grocer
SELECT  *
into #grocer
FROM    
(
select 1 as position , 'bagger' as title, 100 as income
    union
select 2 as position , 'cashier' as title, 120 as income
) a


--for whenever id 1 is logged in:
SELECT  a.userid as Id, b.job_title, c.title as position, c.income
FROM    #info a
    inner join #job b
        on a.job_id = b.job_id
    inner join #army c
        on a.position = c.position
where a.userid = 1

--for whenever id 2 is logged in:
SELECT  a.userid as Id, b.job_title, c.title as position, d.income
FROM    #info a
    inner join #job b
        on a.job_id = b.job_id
    inner join #army c
        on a.position = c.position
    inner join #grocer d
        on c.position = d.position
where a.userid = 2
```